# Is there a way to download the crosswalk runtime after the app has been installed on android?

Tags: android-webview, crosswalk-runtime

Compiling an app with [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) through cordova would increase the size of the app by approximately [20 Mb](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Distributing-Crosswalk-Project-applications).

So, I was thinking if downloading and running code on crosswalk runtime after the application is installed would work. If this works then I would download and use crosswalk runtime on certain Android platforms (< Android 4.4.3) only. And use webview on remaining platforms. Just want to avoid building two different apps with same code for different platforms.

Comment: Same problem, but seem impossible.